# JavaScript will not run a second time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am running a script using `$(document).ready()` it is performing the way I want it to on load up, however, the same script needs to be ran when an html select control is changed.

What I need ultimately is for the filter and sort to run on initial load with sorting on Low to High, and then after the page is loading the user should be able to select any select control and filter and sort as they wish.

Go to http://webtest.ipam.ucla.edu to view the code and on the bottom of the page you can download the folder with all of the files.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Is it `jQuery`? I am assuming it is because of the syntax. If it is please re-tag your question adding `jQuery`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your help, this is now fixed. The way i did it was to encapsulate the $(function(){}) in another function (filtersortProcess()) and then created another script that autoselects the Low to High option and calls filtersortProcess() on windows.load.

Within the $(function(){}) I added a variable (complete) and set it to 1 when it goes within the actual filter process, then after the filter process (if the code exits before completing the process) I check for the complete variable and do a simple filter and sort on the data and with all of this it works great.

Thank you again.

Answer (score 5):

You can put all your reusable logic into a function:

```
function myPrettyJavaScriptLogic () {
   // All the code that you want to reuse in here
}
```

Then you can call the above function both from `document.ready()` and also from the `onchange` handler of your select control.

Answer (score 1):

Create a function outside of your doc ready closure and call it when you need to. Example is jQuery but doc ready is the same event:

```
var doSomethingCool = function( coolStuff ) {
    // Do cool stuff
}

$(function(){
  doSomethingCool( $(this) );

  $('#selectControlId').change(function(e){
    doSomethingCool();
  });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are referencing the .ready function I'm assuming you are actually using jQuery.

$(document).ready()  or jQuery(document).ready()

Anything within the ready() function will only be called once - when the page is loaded.  It waits until the entire DOM is loaded before executing that code.

You can extract out your functionality to a separate function to get kicked off based on your select control changing.

You may benefit from reading a jQuery tutorial I wrote the other week:
http://chadcarter.net/jquery-goodness/

Also, the actual .change event in the jQuery API is here:
http://api.jquery.com/change/

Assuming you want the functionality to be called when the page loads and when the option is changed you will want to create a new function and have that function called inside of both the .ready and the .change functions.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried your answer but a couple of things got messed up, 1. the sort only works now with the first option and 2. when the filters get selected and then unselected everything dissappears. I created a function called filtersortProcess, wihtin the (document).ready() I called the function filtersortProcess and on the change events of all of the option boxes I called the function filtersortProcess on the onchange event.    PLEASE HELP!!!!

Answer (score 0):

put your script in a Named function. call it in domready and select.change().

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set up a handler for the `select` box's `onChange` event.  What I would do is pull out the code you need to execute into a separate function and then do something like

```
function dostuff(){
//do whatever you need to
}

$(document).ready(function() {
   dostuff();
}

<select onchange"dostuff()" >... </select>
```

Note this was quick and dirty, just to give you an idea.

Check out [this link](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=html+select+on+change) for more about `select`'s `onchange`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `jQuery`, which I will assume you are because of this syntax, you just have to bind the event `onchange` to the element.

```
$("element").bind("change", function() { /* your logic */ });
```

You have to run this code after the element is rendered. If you place this code inside the `$(document).ready` there will be no problem. but the whole page will have to load before the even is bound.

So you can do the following:

```
<select id="sel">
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
</select>
```

Then bind the event `change`.

```
$(function() {   /* equivalent to document.ready */
    $("#sel").bind("change", function() {
        /* code that runs when the selection change */
    });
});
```

Comment: .bind('change') is the same as .change(). Lets not confuse the poor OP with the whole bind vs live difference.

Comment: How would I go about letting you guys view my html page. This is massively confusing me.

Comment: @matt: It would be nice if you'd show us the code or give us some more info.

Comment: do you really want me to past all the code with the html page?

Comment: @matt: You can paste it here http://pastebin.com/ if you don't want your post to be extremely big, and then post just the generated link.

Comment: Here is the link that I put the entire website one, its only one page CLICK HERE --> http://webtest.ipam.ucla.edu and at the bottom if you need to test something out I provided the zip folder for download

Comment: I don't get it, your site seems to be working as you described. But if you need to run the script again, wrap everything in another function. Then use `$(function(){ DoStuff(); });`. And on each `select` element use `$("select").change(DoStuff)`. This will execute the function when the value changes.

Comment: when you first load the page up, I need it to be sorted automatically on load up from Low to High. It is not doing this part. When I try to do a (document).ready({ DoStuff();}) and then $("select").change(DoStuff) the sort works and the filterws work, but once the boxes dissappear they wont come back when the filter should show something